# Why Spring Boot and Themeleaf wrongly convert an entity type field into a form field?

Tags: spring, spring-boot, constructor, entity

I make a Spring boot & Spring Data JPA & Hibernate & Thymeleaf App web.

I have simple entities.

pseudocode:

```
@MappedSuperclass
public abstract class Base {

    @Id
    protected Long id;

    public Base() {};

    public Base(Long id) { 
       this.id = id; 
    }

    getter/setter;
}

@Entity
@table(name= "contract_type")
public class ContractType extends AbsBaseEntity {

    @Column
    private String name;

    public Customer() { 
       super(); 
    };

    String toString() {
    
        return name;
    }

    String toString() {
    
        return name;
    }

    getter/setter;
}


@Entity
@table(name= "customer")
public class Customer extends AbsBaseEntity {

    @Column
    private String name;

    public Customer() { 
       super(); 
    };


    // PROBLEM 
    public Customer(String name) { 
       super(); 
       this.name= name;
    };

    String toString() {
    
        return name;
    }
    
    getter/setter;
}


@Entity
@table(name= "contract")
public class Contract extends AbsBaseEntity {

    @Column
    private String code;

    @ManyToOne(optional = false)
    @JoinColumn(name = "type_id", nullable = false)
    private ContractType type;

    @ManyToOne(optional = false)
    @JoinColumn(name = "customer_id", nullable = false)
    private Customer customer;

    public Contract() { 
       super(); 
    };

    String toString() {
    
        return code;
    }

    getter/setter;
}
```

I have @Service @Controller classes and @Repository interfaces.
I don't use any custom converter/formatter/propertyEditor.

Data example:

Customer:
id = 1, name = 'John Smith'

ContractType:
id = 1, name = 'Regular'

Contract:
id = 1, code 'CT00001', type_id = 1, customer_id = 1

I make a Contract Thymeleaf view with a form. P.e.:

```
<form th:object="${item}">                     <-- item is customer from Model data.
    <input th:field="*{code}" />
    <input th:field="*{type}" />
    <input th:field="*{customer}" />
</form>
```

Themeleaf translate to:

```
    <input id="code"     name="code"     value="John Smith">
    <input id="type"     name="type"     value="1">             // OK
    <input id="customer" name="customer" value="CT00001">       // ERROR: MUST BE value="1"
```

It's incorrect. The correct must be:

```
    <input id="code"     name="code"     value="John Smith">
    <input id="customer" name="type"     strong textvalue="1">   // OK
    <input id="customer" name="customer" value="1">              // OK
```

I don't know how to convert from the entity to the form field. I tried to debug it but gave up.

Why type field works but customer field doesn't?
Looking at the Customer and ContractType code I saw that only one contructor was different.

```
   public Customer(String name) { 
      super(); 
      this.name= name;
   };
```

**I delete and it works!**

I have not seen that for entities to function properly they must comply with this restriction.
Its a bug?

Answer (score 0):

I delete:

```
   public Customer(String name) { 
      super(); 
      this.name= name;
   };
```